# Eval only emitting on training begin and training end on CloudML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

Using the code below - eval only runs twice (begin and end) when training on CloudML.   I would expect this eval at least every 10 seconds.

If I run the same code locally this behaves as expected.

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
                   input_fn = read_dataset('{}/test*'.format(OUTPUT_GCS), mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL),
                   steps = 5,
                   start_delay_secs = 2, 
                   throttle_secs = 10, 
                   exporters = exporter)

My batch size is 64 and --scale-tier=BASIC.

Comment: For local run, did you use 'gcloud ml-engine' local model or launch your script using 'python' directly? It might be related to how we populate the environment variable TF_CONFIG.

Comment: What is the Exporter being used? If I am not mistaken eval is only run on exported models.

Comment: I am using LatestExporter.

Comment: Local run is directly in Datalab - no CloudML involved.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. When running in CloudML the underlying checkpoint config is overridden differently than when running locally say in Datalab.

Setting:
 my_checkpointing_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs = 1*60,  keep_checkpoint_max = 3)

On your estimator's congfig property fixes the problem.

Ironically, the docs state this as such, but in two different sections:

1)throttle_secs: Int. Do not re-evaluate unless the last evaluation was started at least this many seconds ago. Of course, evaluation does not occur if no new checkpoints are available, hence, this is the minimum ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py#L217)).

2)By default, the Estimator saves checkpoints in the model_dir according to the following schedule ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/checkpoints#checkpointing_frequency)):

Writes a checkpoint every 10 minutes (600 seconds).
Writes a checkpoint when the train method starts (first iteration) and completes (final iteration).
Retains only the 5 most recent checkpoints in the directory.

This is relative to the default settings of the execution environment.